# Disable DLogs in the code xcode iOS objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

**Basically, I have the DLog command in my project, i have almost hundreds of them. No i am building a release build and i want the compiler to ignore all my DLogs. One way i think of is go to every line where this DLog is and put an if condition only DLog

```
 if(Debug) {DLog(.....)}
```

I am wondering is there a one place i can make the compiler ignore all these DLogs for release?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you defined the DLog add an compiler directive :

```
#ifndef DLog
#   ifdef DEBUG
#       define DLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#   else
#       define DLog( ...)
#   endif // NDEBUG
#endif // DLog
```